# Filtering image collection - only one image from a certain date

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, image, data-collection

My code generates an image collection. In the collection, there are multiple images from the same date (probably from different tiles). Is there a way to filter it and get only one image from a certain date? It's not important which image stays in the collection.

my code:

```
var image_collection = "COPERNICUS/S2_SR";//image collection.
var first_date       = '2019-06-01'; // First date in image collection
var last_date        = '2019-10-10' ;// Last date in image collection
    
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(user_account+folder+shpfile_name).sort('Spatial_ID');
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection(image_collection)
        .filterDate(first_date, last_date)
        .filterBounds(fc)
        .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 18);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print(S2);
print(fc)  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a4c95f9ad22e197795db7023c0a09269) allows having some control of selecting dates in Image Collection. It includes an arbitrary fc geometry in USA.

```
var fc = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-104.60946499778431, 36.501117552980226],
          [-104.60946499778431, 35.86265852547925],
          [-103.45590054465931, 35.86265852547925],
          [-103.45590054465931, 36.501117552980226]]], null, false);

var image_collection = "COPERNICUS/S2_SR";//image collection.
var first_date       = '2019-06-01'; // First date in image collection
var last_date        = '2019-10-10' ;// Last date in image collection
    
//var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(user_account+folder+shpfile_name).sort('Spatial_ID');
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection(image_collection)
        .filterDate(first_date, last_date)
        .filterBounds(fc)
        .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 18);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print(S2);
print(fc);

var allDates = ee.List(S2.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });

//print all simple dates in collection
print(allDatesSimple);

var allDatesSimple_d = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  }).distinct();

//print all not repeated simple dates in collection not repeated 
print(allDatesSimple_d);

var listOfImages = S2.toList(S2.size());

// fourth image of 2019-07-08: id 34 in allDatesSimple list
print(ee.Date(ee.Image(listOfImages.get(34)).get('system:time_start')).format());
```

After running it in GEE code editor, it was printed an Image Collection with 124 images. The **allDatesSimple** function prints all dates (including repeated dates) in that collection. The **allDatesSimple_d** function considers only distinct dates (list has 40 elements) corroborating there are multiple images for almost all simple dates (one exception is 2019-09-08).

If I want consider fourth image of 2019-07-08, it has an id 34 in **allDatesSimple** list. It is corroborated in print statement after converting original Image Collection to List:

```
.
.
.    print(ee.Date(ee.Image(listOfImages.get(34)).get('system:time_start')).format());
.
.
.
```

For using this image in your code you can define corresponding variable selecting element with id 34 in **listOfImages**.

**Editing Note**:

For returning the list of 40 images back, not repeated, you only need to calculate accumulated frequencies in **allDatesSimple** list. It is necessary to include in former script following code lines:

```
.
.
.
var countFreq = allDatesSimple_d.map( function freqDates (ele) {
  
  var list = ee.List([]);
  
  var f = allDatesSimple.frequency(ele);
  
  list = list.add(f);
  
  return list;

}).flatten();

var freqAccum = ee.Array(countFreq).accum(0).toList().insert(0, 0).slice(0, 40);

print(freqAccum);

var new_coll = freqAccum.map( function selectNewColl (ele) {
  
  var new_list = listOfImages.get(ele);
  
  return new_list;
  
});

print("As list of Images", new_coll);

new_coll = ee.ImageCollection(new_coll);

print("As Image Collection", new_coll);
```

Full code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ccd67ca900513e344cba80094d9c31b6).

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. Now how do I return the list of 40 images back to an image collection? I want an image collection of just the 40 images list.

Comment: For returning the list of 40 images back, not repeated, you only need to calculate accumulated frequencies in **allDatesSimple** list. Please, see my **Editing Note**. By the way, If this answer was helpful consider mark it as accepted.