# GEE: exporting daily mean cloud cover

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p

I am trying to export a csv of daily mean cloud cover in the Netherlands according to S5P data. I have calculated the mean cloud fraction, but the exported csv shows many, many rows - none of them are cloud_fraction (image below). What am I missing?

```
//  1. Setup
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0");
var NL = countries.filterMetadata('ADM0_NAME', 'equals', 'Netherlands');
var start_period = ee.Date('2018-07-01');
var end_period = ee.Date(new Date().getTime());

var clouds = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_CLOUD')
  .select('cloud_fraction')
  .filterDate(start_period, end_period);

var cloudNL=clouds.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(NL)//.resample('bilinear').reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 2000);
});


//  2. Mean cloud cover dictionary for entire collection
var cloudlist = cloudNL.map(function(image){
  var meandict = image.select('cloud_fraction').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: NL
  })
  return image.set(meandict); 
});

Export.table.toDrive(cloudlist.sort('cloud_fraction'), 'NL_mean_cloud_fraction');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASNWER: Include `'cloud_fraction'` in a list of properties of `cloudlist` to export using the `selectors` argument. Example:

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: cloudlist.sort('cloud_fraction'),
  description: 'NL_mean_cloud_fraction',
  selectors:['system:time_start','cloud_fraction']
});
```

EXPLANATION: `'cloud_fraction'` didn't appear in your exported .csv is because of null values set for this property in the function you mapped onto `cloudNL`. It is not possible to set an image property to have a null value. This can be shown by:

```
var image = ee.Image().set('dummy',null)
print(image.propertyNames()) // there is no 'dummy' property in the returned list
```

If the `selectors` argument is not defined in `Export.table.toDirive`, I'm guessing that the function sets `selectors` to be all of the properties of the first entry in the exported collection. If `'cloud_fraction'` was set to null in that first entry, then this property would be deselected from your exported .csv -- which would be the case since `cloudlist` was sorted by `'cloud_fraction'` (null values came first).

EDIT: the following example filters `cloudlist` by `'cloud_fraction'` and adds a new property, which we will call `'datestring'`:

```
cloudlist = cloudlist

   // keep images with cloud_fraction less than 0.1 
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('cloud_fraction',0.1))
  
  .map(function(image){
    
    // extract the first 8 characters from system:index using ee.String.slice
    var datestring = ee.String(image.get('system:index')).slice(0,8)
    return image.set('datestring', datestring)
  })
```

Note, you will have to add `datestring` to your list of properties to export as a table.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see where I explicitly the set cloud_fraction values to null?

The csv export now works, but the cloud_fraction column is still completely empty.

Comment: The majority of your images do not intersect with your area of interest (`NL`), so when you reduce your image a null is returned. If you are still sorting your exported collection by `'cloud_fraction`', the non-null entires should be at the end of the .csv. Might be useful to filter `cloudlist` using `Filter.notNull`, example: `cloudlist.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['cloud_fraction']))`

Comment: I realized that the images with cloud_fraction values were simply further down in the Excel. Using .notNull worked for me, thanks! In addition to that, could I keep only values lower than 0.10? 
And furthermore, could I directly split the system:time attributes before the first 'T', so I only keep e.g. 20200721 as a title?

Comment: Glad to hear things are working for you, @Olivier. See my editted answer for my response to your questions.

Comment: Ah I forgot about the .slice command! Used it in the past. Very last question. On some dates, there are two passovers (and thus images). Is there a simple way to remove duplicates, or even better, remove the duplicate furthest from 'T14' in the string name? For example: remove 20180712T11... but keep 20180712T12...

Comment: @Olivier, I suggest that you post these follow-up question seperately, since your original question has been answered. At this time, I cannot help you with this last question. I recall a similar question being asked recently: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387693/filtering-image-collection-only-one-image-from-a-certain-date. All the best.

Comment: Also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388027/remove-duplicates-from-an-image-collection-in-google-earth-engine